# Difference between .edmx file and creating an Entities.cs file

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3

I have looked at two of Microsoft's tutorials for MVC.   In one tutorial they are creating a .edmx file to handle the Entity Framework in order to execute Linq queries.  In another tutorial they made a class called "MusicStoreEntities.cs"  here is the code:

```
using System.Data.Entity;

namespace MvcMusicStore.Models
{
    public class MusicStoreEntities : DbContext
    {
        public DbSet<Album>     Albums  { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Genre>     Genres  { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Artist>    Artists { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Cart>      Carts { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Order>     Orders { get; set; }
        public DbSet<OrderDetail> OrderDetails { get; set; }
    }
}
```

And the tutorial creates an instance of this class and starts doing Linq queries as well.  What are the differences between these 2 methods? and how can I make DbSet objects in a .edmx file?  Thank you.

Comment: Check out [this post](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/ff830362) on Model-First in the Entity Framework 4.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are various ways to create your model structure.

1. You can code [POCO](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plain_Old_CLR_Object) classes first, and create the database manually.
2. You can code [POCO](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plain_Old_CLR_Object) classes first, and create the database automatically using code first libraries.
3. You can create your database schema, and import it into a class diagram (which will supply all the models and navigation).
4. You can create your class diagram, and create your database schema from that.

1 and 2 create only the cs, while 3 and 4 create the edmx.

You can check [this](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2010/07/16/code-first-development-with-entity-framework-4.aspx) for Code First EF (this includes the DbSet part of your question).

EDIT: You can even use POCO classes with an existing database, as posted [here](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2010/08/03/using-ef-code-first-with-an-existing-database.aspx).